# Apache web-server shared document root on windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, apache, document-root, linux-mint

I am a web developer and I have windows 8.1 and linux mint 16 both installed on the same machine and both has LAMP stack installed.

Is there a ways to share the same document root and database on both systems?

Comment: Sure - you should be able to specify any path as the document root.

Answer (score 1):

I should start out by saying that this is a development setup on a private network, I would not suggest this for production computers.

I had a similar problem that I solved by mapping a Drive on Windows, which is where Apache is running, to the Host Mac OSX 10.8.5. (Kinda like Linux) You should be able to adapt to your flavor of linux in 1st step.

1st, in Mac File Sharing I created a share that was accessible to everyone.
2nd, I mapped a drive in Windows to the VMware host as such; "\\\\vmware-host\\Shared Folders\\stevek\\development" as the Y: drive.
3rd, I modified the file C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf
Unfortunately I found that Apache has permission problems connecting to the folder as the Y: drive, so I used the UNC path in httpd.conf like this;

DocumentRoot "\\\\vmware-host\\Shared Folders\\stevek\\development"

and

<Directory "\\\\vmware-host\\Shared Folders\\stevek\\development">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

I am no Mac/Win/VMware permissions guru but near as I can tell, mapping the drive provides the permissions so that Apache can use the UNC path.